# Getting an error when subscribing a queue

Tags: node.js, vue.js, rabbitmq, node-amqplib

My backend pushes messages to rabbitmq queue and I need to fetch those messages to display in the frontend part of the messages, since the messages have to be in specific order, I cannot use an asynchronous approach.

I have written this code

```
var open require("amqplib").connect("amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5682");
var queue = "developer";

export default {
    name: 'Subsriber',
    data: function() {
        return {
            selected: "",
            services: [],
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        var url = "http://10.0.9.134:5060/services/scripts";
        this.services = []; // empty the existing list first.
        setTimeout(() => {
            axios.get(url)
            .then(response => {
            this.services = response.data;
            })
        }, 2000)

        open.then(function(conn){
            return conn.createChannel();
        }).then(function(ch){
            return ch.assertQueue(queue).then(function(ok){
                return ch.consume(queue, function(msg){
                    if (msg != null){
                        console.log(msg.content.toString());
                    }
                });
            });
        });

    }
```

but I get this error:

```
"Unhandled rejection TypeError: QS.unescape is not a function
    openFrames@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/_amqplib@0.5.2@amqplib/lib/connect.js:50:1
    connect@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/_amqplib@0.5.2@amqplib/lib/connect.js:145:14
    connect/<@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/_amqplib@0.5.2@amqplib/channel_api.js:7:12
    connect@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/_amqplib@0.5.2@amqplib/channel_api.js:6:10
    @webpack-internal:///./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/components/SelectServices.vue:56:12
    ["./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/components/SelectServices.vue"]@http://10.0.9.134/app.js:1251:1
    __webpack_require__@http://10.0.9.134/app.js:679:1
    hotCreateRequire/fn@http://10.0.9.134/app.js:89:20
    @webpack-internal:///./src/components/SelectServices.vue:1:148
    ["./src/components/SelectServices.vue"]@http://10.0.9.134/app.js:1804:1
    __webpack_require__@http://10.0.9.134/app.js:679:1
    hotCreateRequire/fn@http://10.0.9.134/app.js:89:20
    @webpack-internal:///./src/router/index.js:4:85
    ["./src/router/index.js"]@http://10.0.9.134/app.js:1820:1
    __webpack_require__@http://10.0.9.134/app.js:679:1
    hotCreateRequire/fn@http://10.0.9.134/app.js:89:20
    @webpack-internal:///./src/main.js:4:66
    ["./src/main.js"]@http://10.0.9.134/app.js:1812:1
    __webpack_require__@http://10.0.9.134/app.js:679:1
    hotCreateRequire/fn@http://10.9.0.134/app.js:89:20
    [0]@http://10.9.1.147/app.js:1829:18
    __webpack_require__@http://10.0.9.134/app.js:679:1
    @http://10.9.0.134/app.js:725:18
    @http://10.9.0.134/app.js:1:1"
```